# SQLite Group_Concat

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need a SQLite query for an Android App, and I'm not quite getting it.
From a bit of research, I got a possible solution, but I haven't manage to make it work yet, so it probably doesn't work in SQLite.
I have a table with the following schema:

```
DAY  | PERSON | SCORE
---------------------
  1  | PERS1  | A
  1  | PERS2  | A
  1  | PERS3  | A
  1  | PERS4  | B
  1  | PERS5  | B
  1  | PERS6  | B
  2  | PERS1  | C
  2  | PERS2  | C
  2  | PERS3  | C
  2  | PERS4  | C
  2  | PERS5  | C
  2  | PERS6  | C
```

I need a query that gives me the concatenations of every PERSON with the same scores for each day, with the result of the query being presented in the following format:

```
DAY | RES_A             | RES_B             | RES_C
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | PERS1+PERS2+PERS3 | PERS4+PERS5+PERS6 | NULL
2   | NULL              | NULL              | PERS1+PERS2+PERS3+PERS4+PERS5+PERS6
```

There's only 3 types of possible results, so the query will always return the same number of columns.
The solution I've been trying for the 'RES_A' column (for example) is this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(SCORE = 'A', CONCAT('+', PERSON), '') SEPARATOR '') AS 'RES_A'
```

But Java says "E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "SEPARATOR": syntax error", so I guess the keyword 'SEPARATOR' is not valid for SQLite.

Can you help me with this query?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using BETWEEN with a WHERE would you post your query string

Comment: my bad you did post the query string take a look at this link SEPARATOR not found https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CASE expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) and the second parameter of [group_concat()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat):

```
SELECT Day,
       group_concat(CASE Score WHEN 'A' THEN Person END, '+') AS Res_A,
       group_concat(CASE Score WHEN 'B' THEN Person END, '+') AS Res_B,
       group_concat(CASE Score WHEN 'C' THEN Person END, '+') AS Res_C
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Day;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
SELECT 
    DAY,
    group_concat(concat) AS RES_A
FROM (
    SELECT
        DAY,
        CASE 
            WHEN SCORE IS 'A' THEN PERSON
        END AS concat
    FROM (YOUR_TABLE_NAME)
)
GROUP BY DAY
```